# XCode Cocoapods workspace manually add new files and file not found

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I am using VideoCore (https://github.com/jgh-/VideoCore) and I want to add newer version of the project than the one on CocoaPods. So I started off by manually updating new source to the one from Cocoapods. Compiling gives me error including header within the VideoCore Cocoapods project in the following includes:

```
#include <videocore/filters/FilterFactory.h>
#include <videocore/filters/Basic/BasicVideoFilterBGRA.h>

// The following line chokes
#include <videocore/filters/Basic/GrayscaleVideoFilter.h> 
#include <videocore/filters/Basic/InvertColorsVideoFilter.h>
#include <videocore/filters/Basic/SepiaVideoFilter.h>
```

GrayscaleVideoFilter.h is in there just like BasicVideoFilterBGRA.h. But Somehow it cannot be found.

The header is in `Pods-VideoCore` target (project header) like the other headers. So what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of updating the source manually, tell cocoapods you want the latest code, not simply the latest release. See https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/the-podfile.html.

e.g., in your Podfile, to grab the very latest code

```
pod 'VideoCore', :head
```

Comment: Thanks this works. Suppose I want to add new files to it manually, how would I do it?

Comment: If you're modifying the cocoapods install, you're on your own! I would pull VideoCore out of cocoapods and add the files manually to your project. You might need to add its path to the project's Header Search Paths.